# Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip'

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am using Android studio 0.4.6.
Whenever I build it says `Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip'.`

I am new for gradle.

This is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

I have only one module and module's build.gradle is as follows

```
apply plugin: 'android'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 8
            targetSdkVersion 19
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                runProguard false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    }
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: Are your shore that you use Android studio 0.4.6?

Comment: There are going to be more error messages than that; please post the contents of your Gradle console window after the build fails.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have gradle installed in your machine on below path

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.10-all\6vpvhqu0efs1fqmqr2decq1v12
```

And using default gradle wrapper under

```
File > Settings > Gradle
```

If not check whether you are able to access the below link from your browser or not

```
http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

If you are using proxy make sure you have cofigured proxy settings in your gradle configuration and on Android Studio.

Comment: I have gradle installed at path `C:\Users\ravindra.kambale\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.10-all\6vpvhqu0efs1fqmqr2decq1v12` And I am able to download the file from location `http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip`. But still the same issue...

Comment: Can you please include your module's build.gradle file, if multiple include all .

Comment: everything looks fine check your `Event Log` and `Gradle Console` if they are more descriptive about the problem.

Comment: @ravindra.kamble, did you solve the issue? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

In my case something happend with JDK path. Try to refresh your JDK home path in project Structure->SDKs.

Comment: it happened to me also

Answer (score 0):

Go through the complete stack trace of the error. In my case, the first line of the error was same as this. But the problem was, another Gradle build from the terminal was holding the lock, that prevented the eclipse to import/build.